# help with steam

Tags: drivers, games, steam

when I run steam my computer it keep saying that I don't have the latest Nvidia drivers.

I use Additional drives and it said that I have the latest one. I UN-install and re-install the divers but it still say the same thing. please help. Sorry I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu , Don't worry we are here to help you.

Comment: If you are new to linux, I guess you should not be testing Steam :) Sorry to say so, but Steam is not production ready so don't expect miracles.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing the newest *experimental* drivers? Perhaps named `nvidia-experimental-NNN`? I haven't tried this, but I read that it can fix the graphics driver issues with steam.

Answer (score 0):

First go to dash and search **Additional  Drivers**,  open it . It will check your system and suggest to install missing drivers. You will get list of different Nvidia drivers , But you have to select only **recommanded** version.